# Does Symfony have an interface for ORMs?

Tags: php, symfony, orm

I wonder if there is an interface that diverse ORM should implement for Symfony or not.

The question came up when I was building a service that accepts an ORM (Doctrine right now), and wanted to declare type.

I guess different ORM have different behaviour and classes... in those cases, how can build entities that do not depend on specific ORM in case one wants to switch later?

Comment: Symfony does not have any ORM interfaces.  Doctrine itself has different layers and in particular has Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager and ObjectRepository interfaces.  Any ORM that implements those two interfaces could (in theory) be plugged in without much change.  I don't know of any other ORMs that do that.  To be honest, it is pretty unrealistic to expect that something like an ORM can be swapped out.   Too many subtle differences will crop up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, Symfony is agnostic in regard to your choice of ORM.

The [standard edition](https://symfony.com/distributions) comes bundled with Doctrine and also contains some “bridge” code to ease the integration.

However, you can use any ORM you’d like to. For example, Propel is known to work well with Symfony, too. The Propel team also maintains an [integration bundle](https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle).

There is no “interface” in the sense of a formal description an ORM has to comply with. There is no such thing as `interface SymfonyOrmInterface {}`.

Think about it, how and why should Symfony demand this? Symfony is a HTTP framework built on a set of loosely coupled components. Most of these components don’t even know what an ORM is or if one is currently available in the application.

You will usually install your ORM through composer, and it will be available in your business code (assuming that it supports autoloading with PSR-0/-4).

Of course, for a proper integration of an ORM into Symfony, there are some conventions and features, such as:

- CLI commands, e.g. for schema updates,
- Managing configuration values through the global config.yml and parameters.yml files,
- Providing services and dependencies through Dependency Injection.

These are implemented in integration bundles, usually provided by the respective ORM vendor.

For your business code, this means that you can’t just replace one ORM with another one. There are significant differences accross ORMs in regard to storage abstraction, caching, querying, hydration, etc. Replacing an ORM will always require you to adapt your business logic to some exent, and not only in a Symfony project.

Comment: But is there an interface that those ORM should implement?

Comment: No, Symfony doesn't declare that. How are you imagine this interface? Another abstraction layer over many ORMs? http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/170619/257809

Comment: you can go with interfaces and implementation per storage, like Users (as an interface) and DoctrineUsers (as an implementation for doctrine that has Doctrine classes injected).